# Electron gun design

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electronics

I have a question about electron guns. I have read a lot, and all designs use high NEGATIVE voltage ($-1000$ V for example). Is possible to use high POSITIVE voltage like this drawing? Or do you think it will not work this way?

Considering that all the chamber walls are at ground voltage ($0$ V) in both cases.

[image]

Comment: Not sure we want to design guns on here.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Electrons will travel to a more positive electrode.  The transformer isolates the cathode so it can be raised or lowered to any voltage.

Comment: In either case you will get electrons from the cathode accelerated by the anode. That is fine. The real question is what happens to the electrons after they pass through the anode. If your target is back at ground potential, the electrons are decelerating from the anode to the target in the approach on the right. Overall, the cathode has to be net negative potential relative to where the electrons end up for the electrons to have any energy once they get there.

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but I thought voltage (or potential difference) refers to the ratio between the voltages at two points; giving me the impression that these two diagrams are exactly the same?

Comment: It does not make sense to say that voltage is the ratio between voltages.

Comment: I explained it badly but the gist is that it is to do with the difference between two points