# Electron gun voltages

Tags: electrostatics, particle-physics, electrons, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I saw on the internet that catode of electoron gun should have negative potential to zero (ground). On the other hand catodes of tv CRTs were grounded and anodes were connented to positive high voltage. What is difference between this two conceptions? I know that it doesn't matter to accelerating emissed electrons. I think that there could be deference in emission of electrons. It should be easier to get free electron out of catode (-hv case) than get electrons by making positive ionts (0 V case). Am I right? I think that advantage of grounded anode can be zero potential to the rest of machine. So there wouldn't be complications while isolating anode. (it doesn't matter in CRT becouse they were made of glass)

My two situations are same like in question [Electron gun design](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482383/electron-gun-design) which was not answered. I hope that anyone will understand my question and reply to my theories. I am asking, becouse I want to make my own electron gun. I have power supply which has 0 and +hv at the output. So I need to know if I can use my power supply or try to modify it what wouldn't be easy.

Comment: As I noted on your other question: 
In either case you will get electrons from the cathode accelerated by the anode. That is fine. The real question is what happens to the electrons after they pass through the anode. If your target is back at ground potential, the electrons are decelerating from the anode to the target in the approach on the right. Overall, the cathode has to be net negative potential relative to where the electrons end up for the electrons to have any energy once they get there.

Comment: @JonCuster so at conclusion, for firing to uncharged target is efficient only negative-cathode version. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: Not charge, potential. There certainly are systems where the target is held at a potential other than ground, used in both electron and ion systems.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. Maybe for right functionality of positive anode there should be only pulse. But even in that case there would be less efficient.